# C# vs VB.NET in terms of tool support?

Tags: c#, vb.net

While for the most part you can generate the same MSIL, there are definitely differences in tooling.  [PEX](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/Pex/), for example, works much easier with C#.

What Microsoft or 3rd party tools don't work equally well for both languages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess that answer depends on what you mean by tooling support.

For example, when it comes to IDE support, VB does a lot more than what C# does. It just has a better IDE.

It has extremely good background compilation and really good intellisence.

When it comes to support for MS research projects, or "new" platforms like the XBox, VB will probably lag behind C#.

For things done by the MS Developer Division, or Office, you should expect more or less equal support between the two languages.

For other groups, like the MS research project you mentioned, multi language parity is often not a priority. In those cases they seem to tend to go with C# as their default choice.

Comment: Good info, but would be more useful in a list format I think.

Comment: C# also has better intellisense.  No need to Ctrl + enter to get object/method names.  I don't really agree with the IDE part, but the background compilation is nice.

Comment: I used to like the VB intellisense and background compilation in the IDE but since I started doing TDD it just gets in the way, so I moved to C# that + other reasons

Comment: Who said you needed ctrl+enter for vb?  That's just not the case.

Comment: Intellisense for VB.NET and C# are equivalent. At least in VS2008, don't remember in previous VS versions.

Comment: There are differences between them.

One example is "keyword" intellisence. C# just adds keywords to the completion list. VB actually limits the keywords that are shown based on what you type.

There are other differences, like with queries.

Answer (score 1):

Ektron CMS 400 is definitely more VB than C#. But if you're using Ektron, you've got bigger problems to worry about...

Answer (score 1):

Re-sharper has heaps more support for C# than VB in the code analysis side of things.

Theres a full list [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/index.html) of the differences between VB and C# .NET

Comment: Resharper absolutely rocks. I couldn't live without it.

Answer (score 0):

One big missing for VB.NET is [StyleCop](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis) I hope that they Dev Team will provide also a VB.NET version.

Answer (score 0):

**Better Support for C#**

- StyleCop
- PEX
- Re-sharper

**Better Support for VB.NET**

- Intellisense

(It's wiki... please add more)